# Can I reset a specified variable of keras when training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Can I reinitialize or reset a variable at the begin of every training batch in keras?

Here's a toy example:

```py
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np

x = Input(shape=(None, 4))

def toy_test():
    m = K.zeros(shape=(16, 9), dtype="int32")

    # computation here, some elements of m will be changed here
    m = m[2, 3].assign(m[2, 3]+1)

    result = (K.sum(K.cast(m > 1, dtype="float32"))) / (K.sum(K.cast(m >= 1, dtype="float32")) + 1e-4)

    # I want to reset m to all zeros
    m = K.zeros(shape=(16, 9), dtype="int32")

    return result

r= toy_test()
model = Model([x], outputs=x)
model.add_loss(r)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-5))

test_x = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]],
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]],
])
history = model.fit(x=test_x, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```

Expected result:

1/2 loss: 0.0

2/2 loss: 0.0

Actual result:

1/2 loss: 0.0000e+00

2/2 loss: 0.4999

It seems that the variable is only initialized once and remains without reset at second batch. How can I reset `m` to all zeros?

It seems `tf.control_dependencies` may can be used to control the flow of computation, but can it be used to control variable?

Comment: Do you mean at the beginning of each epoch? Also, `m` is not a variable!

Comment: @rvinas Actually I want to reset `m` at the begining of each step, but at the beginning of each epoch is also appreciated. 
And `K.zeros` does return a variable as the [document](https://keras.io/backend/#zeros) says.
And `type(m)` return `tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable`

Comment: I don't really understand the question, isn't the value of `m` always the same when you compute `result`?

Comment: @rvinas Some elements of `m` will be changed in ```python     # computation here, some elements of m will be changed (according to the batch data) here
    m = m[2, 3].assign(m[2, 3]+1)```, and I want to reset `m` to all zeros after I get `result` of current batch

Comment: In this case, would it work to declare `m` as a constant, so that it always has the same value when computing `result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve it by using `tf.control_dependencies`.
Here is the modified part of `toy_test`:

```py
def toy_test():
    m = tf.get_variable(shape=(16, 9), dtype="int32", name='test_m', use_resource=True)
    assign_op = m.assign(np.zeros((16, 9), dtype=int))
    # some computation
    with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
        m = assign_op
        m[2, 3].assign(m[2, 3]+1)
        result = (K.sum(K.cast(m > 1, dtype="float32"))) / (K.sum(K.cast(m >= 1, dtype="float32")) + 1e-4)

    return result
```